# Reading from JSON file in Swift

Tags: json, swift, parsing

I'm trying to read a `JSON` file but I keep getting an error when I try to read the "ParsedText". 
 First I convert the serialized JSON data to a dictionary of type `[String: Any]` and then I try to read the `dictionary["ParsedResults"]` value and convert that to a dictionary of type `[String: Any]` but it always fails.

Here is the JSON file:

```
{
    ErrorDetails = "<null>";
    ErrorMessage = "<null>";
    IsErroredOnProcessing = 0;
    OCRExitCode = 1;
    ParsedResults = ( {
            ErrorDetails = "";
            ErrorMessage = "";
            FileParseExitCode = 1;
            ParsedText = "Sample text";
            TextOverlay = {
                HasOverlay = 0;
                Lines = ( );
                Message = "Text overlay is not provided as it is not requested";
            };
        } );
    ProcessingTimeInMilliseconds = 869;
    SearchablePDFURL = "Searchable PDF not generated as it was not requested.";
}
```

Here is part of the swift function:

```
do {
    //create json object from data
    let dictionary = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as! [String: Any]

    for (key, value) in dictionary {
        print("KEY: \(key)")
        print("VALUE: \(value)")
    }

    let parsedResults = dictionary["ParsedResults"] as! [String: Any]
    print("parsedResults: \(parsedResults)")

   } catch let error {
      print("ERROR: Could not serialize jSON Data: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
   }
```

Comment: Read the JSON. Parentheses mean array. Curly braces mean dictionary.

Comment: This is not valid JSON.

Comment: You don't have the semi-colon in JSON.  You don't separate the key and its value in JSON.

Comment: `let parsedResults = dictionary["ParsedResults"] as! [String: Any]` => `let parsedResults = dictionary["ParsedResults"] as! [[String: Any]]` because `dictionary["ParsedResults"]` is an array of dictionary, then you can do `let parsedResult = parsedResults.first as [String:Any]` For those saying it's not JSON, this seems clearly do be the print of `dictionary`, meaning, the JSON parsed into Swift/Objective-C Objects, what you are expecting is `String.init(data encoding:.utf8)`.

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks @Larme

Answer (score 0):

As already commented, your said-to-be *JSON file* is not in JSON format.

It seems to be in a classic text-based plist format. If you do want to read the file as is, you can use `PropertyListSerialization`:

```
import Foundation

let data = """
{
    ErrorDetails = "<null>";
    ErrorMessage = "<null>";
    IsErroredOnProcessing = 0;
    OCRExitCode = 1;
    ParsedResults = ( {
            ErrorDetails = "";
            ErrorMessage = "";
            FileParseExitCode = 1;
            ParsedText = "Sample text";
            TextOverlay = {
                HasOverlay = 0;
                Lines = ( );
                Message = "Text overlay is not provided as it is not requested";
            };
        } );
    ProcessingTimeInMilliseconds = 869;
    SearchablePDFURL = "Searchable PDF not generated as it was not requested.";
}
""".data(using: .utf8)

do {
    //create property list object from data
    let dictionary = try PropertyListSerialization.propertyList(from: data!, options: [], format: nil) as! [String: Any]

    for (key, value) in dictionary {
        print("KEY: \(key)")
        print("VALUE: \(value)")
    }

    let parsedResults = dictionary["ParsedResults"] as! [[String: Any]] //<- See Larme's comment.
    print("parsedResults: \(parsedResults)")

} catch let error {
    print("ERROR: Could not deserialize plist Data: \(error.localizedDescription)")
}
```

But I recommend you to check the part generating such files, and fix it to generate a valid JSON file.